# General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop. The command "Play" is not currently available

Tags: python, automation, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have person image with white background , and I have one more image which I am going to use it as new background for person. I am trying to do it in photoshop application with python script.

This is the script I have tried,

```
import os
import win32com.client

SILENT_CLOSE = 2

# This actually fires up Photoshop if not already running.
ps = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
ps.DisplayDialogs = 3            # psDisplayNoDialogs
ps.Preferences.RulerUnits = 1    # psPixels

folder_path = r"C:\Users\MCPL-265\Desktop\ps_connect\TEST\Input"

# Get a list of files in the folder
files = os.listdir(folder_path)

output_folder = r"C:\Users\MCPL-265\Desktop\ps_connect\TEST\Output"

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

# Loop through the files and open them in Photoshop
for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
    ps.Open(file_path)

    ps.DoAction("BG", "Actions")

    output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, file)

    jpgSaveOptions = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.JPEGSaveOptions" )
    ps.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(output_file, jpgSaveOptions, True, 2)

ps.Quit() # Stops the Photoshop application
```

But It is throwing this error

```
  File "<COMObject Photoshop.Application>", line 2, in DoAction
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Adobe Photoshop', 'General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.\n- The command "Play" is not currently available.', None, 0, -2147212704), None)
```

Can anyone explain why it's happening?

**Update :**
I tried with the different photoshop versions of 24.5, 23.5.5, 22.2. But still I am getting the same error.
The photoshop version of action file created is same as the version that I am currently using to automate.

Comment: Does the action the script is trying to run exist?

Comment: that is a .atn file i have loaded already in photoshop and available here  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jdB3_DuVqUG2M5eyEp011FFS-lHWqNMo/view)

Comment: I think you are calling the wrong action it should be in the form `ps.DoAction("action name", "action set")` in your case (from the .atn the image): `ps.DoAction("BG", "Set1")`